# RETORNAR VALORES ESPECÍFICOS DE ACORDO COM A DATA [SQL]

Tags: mysql, sql

Bom dia,

Estou travado em uma query que estou desenvolvendo para um projeto. Tenho duas tabelas distintas. A primeira contém os dados cadastrais dos colaboradores. A segunda contém dados da Diretoria que esses colaboradores pertencem e as respectivas mudanças de cargo/salário.

**cadastro_colaborador** [Modelo Tabela Colaborador](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqD7N.png)

**dados_diretoria** [Modelo Tabela Diretoria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2tHj.png)

Preciso que na tabela *cadastro_colaborador* apareça o cargo mais recente de cada colaborador, de acordo com a *dt_fotografia* da tabela *dados_diretoria*. Para isso, estou usando a query abaixo:

```
select 
  dc.nome, 
  dc.matricula, 
  dc.cpf,
  dd.dt_atualizacao
from cadastro_colaborador dc
left join dados_diretoria dd on
  dc.cpf = dd.cpf
where dt_atualizacao = 
  (select max(dt_fotografia) from dados_diretoria)
```

Entretanto, o resultado apresentado é [Tabela Resultado Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBojo.png). Nessa tabela são apresentadas apenas as informações em que a data de atualização máxima é = 31/08/2023. Dessa forma, as informações do Marcio não são exibidas, porque a data de atualização máxima dele é 01/01/2023.

Preciso que a query retorne as informações de cada colaborador de acordo com a dt_atualizacao máxima de cada um, ou seja, as informações da Rebecca, Antonio e Felipe devem ser com base na dt_atualizacao = 31/08/2023. Por outro lado, as informações do Marcio devem ser com base na dt_atualizacao = 01/01/2023.

Qual o erro da minha query original? O que posso fazer para que ela retorne o resultado que preciso?

Obrigado!

Comment: Pelo que entendi ....  dt_atualizacao =  (select max(dt_fotografia) from dados_diretoria dd2 where dd2.cpf = dd.cpf) ....

Answer (score 0):

Teste a select desta maneira:

```
select dc.nome,
       dc.matricula,
       dc.cpf,
       dd.dt_atualizacao
from cadastro_colaborador dc
         left join dados_diretoria dd on
    dc.cpf = dd.cpf
where (dt_atualizacao, dd.cpf) in
      (select max(dt_fotografia), cpf
       from dados_diretoria
       group by cpf)
Dessa forma, ele deve trazer as maiores datas pra cada cpf cadastrado, já que a subselect agrupa os dados por cpf e retorna o valor máximo respectivo a cada um deles.
```

É importante tomar cuidado com o volume de dados, já que o group by pode fazer com que a select demore mais.

- É importante tomar cuidado com o volume de dados, já que o group by pode fazer com que a select demore mais.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).